# Prove Cayley-Hamilton theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, cayley-hamilton

I have a exercise in my linear algebra textbook:

Let $c_2\lambda^2+c_1\lambda +c_0=0$ be the characteristic equation for the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&3\\3&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Prove that $c_2A^2+c_1A +c_0I=0$

This is Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

My solution:

If a root $\lambda$ exists, then it is the eigen value for the eigen vector $\vec{v}$.
If we multiply $c_2A^2+c_1A +c_0I$ with $\vec{v}$ then we get:
$$(c_2\lambda^2+c_1\lambda +c_0)\vec{v}$$
and since the eigen vector is not the zero vector and $c_2\lambda^2+c_1\lambda +c_0=0$ is true, $c_2A^2+c_1A +c_0I=0$ is also true.

Is this enough to prove the theorem and solve the problem?

Comment: Aren't you just supposed to show that this specific matrix satisfies its characteristic equation?

Comment: I think this is just proof by calculation, no?

Comment: I think that is what the question calls for, but I thought I could be clever and sidestep the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say that you've got a proof yet, but you're not far off.

The problem is that you have shown that the eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ is in the kernel of $c_2 A^2 + c_1 A + c_0 I$ (i.e. $(c_2 A^2 + c_1 A + c_0 I) \vec{v} = 0$), but *a priori* the entire matrix $c_2 A^2 + c_1 A + c_0 I$ need not be zero if it maps a single vector nonzero to zero (I suppose unless $A$ were a $1 \times 1$).

On the other hand for this specific $2\times2$ matrix, if you knew that $c_2 A^2 + c_1 A + c_0 I$ mapped two linearly independent vectors to zero then it must be zero (if you like, for dimension reasons). So, what if we actually calculate the characteristic polynomial of $A$, and find that it has two distinct roots (it does)? Then the eigenvectors corresponding to these two roots have to be linearly independent (the roots are $4$ and $-2$, and they must be eigenvalues). Then we can use your argument for each eigenvalue/vector, and then this would complete the proof.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it felt a little to easy.

Comment: Does this proof only work for symmetrical nXn-matrices which have n eigenvectors. If the matrix only hade one eigenvector, then you can't describe all vectors in eigenvectors and for some vectors $(c_2A^2+c_1A+c_0I)\vec{v}\ne 0$ right?

Comment: @ErikEriksson That's right, in other words what I've given here is a proof of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem for the *diagonalizable* matrices. (If your matrix is symmetric, then it is always diagonalizable, so this always works.) The whole proof is a bit more complicated. The whole thing follows, for example, by understanding the characteristic polynomial in terms of the generalized eigenspaces of $A$.

Comment: What goes wrong is basically some nilpotency (see *Jordan canonical form*), and it turns out that the multiplicity of each root of the characteristic polynomial is always enough to kill all of the nilpotent parts.

Comment: (What I'm basically saying here is the equivalent fact that the so-called minimal polynomial of $A$ divides the characteristic polynomial of $A$.)

Comment: You have given me a tempting thread to pull at. Thank you for the thorough response. I don't for see me understanding everything right now, but hopefully the questions you have raised in my head will outlive my first course in linear algebra :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a specific matrix given:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}1&3\\3&1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Its characteristic equation is given by
$$
p(\lambda):=\det(\lambda I - A) = \begin{vmatrix}\lambda-1&-3\\-3&\lambda-1\end{vmatrix}
= (\lambda-1)^2-(-3)^2 = \lambda^2-2\lambda-8.
$$
Now,
$$
A^2=\begin{pmatrix}1&3\\3&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&3\\3&1\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}10&6\\6&10\end{pmatrix}
$$
so
$$
p(A)
= A^2 - 2A - 8I
= \begin{pmatrix}10&6\\6&10\end{pmatrix} - 2 \begin{pmatrix}1&3\\3&1\end{pmatrix} - 8 \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$